# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority when building docker image

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, x509

I have Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM tomcat:jre8
ADD https://nexus-instance/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/apache/activemq/activemq-core/5.7.0/activemq-core-5.7.0.jar $CATALINA_HOME/lib/
```

I want to add jar located in Nexus to the image

When I build the image, it ends up with:

```
Get https://nexus-instance/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/apache/activemq/activemq-core/5.7.0/activemq-core-5.7.0.jar: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to add our local certificate into **ubuntu** store and can find the certificate in **/etc/ssl/certs**

1. What things should one consider?
2. Will docker engine installed on ubuntu host use certificates which
   are trusted ubuntu system-wide?
3. Does Docker handle that in different way?

Comment: Have you tried adding the certificate thru the Docker file? I guess you need to have your certificate inside the docker container producing the image...

Answer (score 0):

After all, I was missing restart of docker engine:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Once it is restarted, the service will pick up newly added certs